# Doing calculations, using mulitple rows, pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Expanding on my previous question. [Return only the last day of the year with pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65183759/return-only-the-last-day-of-the-year-with-pandas?noredirect=1#comment115238809_65183759)

my current table is this

*name of the table is last_six_years*

```
   symbol   date    close
44  MMM 2014-12-31  139.6180
45  MMM 2015-12-31  131.3644
46  MMM 2016-12-30  159.8925
47  MMM 2017-12-29  215.7010
48  MMM 2018-12-31  179.2494
49  MMM 2019-12-31  171.5581
```

i need to create a new column(named "capital_gains_yield") which calculates a value, that is derived from using the next row to it with the following formula:

capital_gains_yield = (current year close - previous year close) / previous year close

meaning, the outcome would look something like this:

```
   symbol   date    close      capital_gains_yield
44  MMM 2014-12-31  139.6180   ...
45  MMM 2015-12-31  131.3644   -0.057
46  MMM 2016-12-30  159.8925   0.2137
47  MMM 2017-12-29  215.7010   0.3522
48  MMM 2018-12-31  179.2494   -0.16
49  MMM 2019-12-31  171.5581   -0.04
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [pandas.DataFrame.pct_change()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html) function.

Assuming you already sorted the dataframe by time:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'close':np.random.uniform(0, 10, 5)})
df['yield'] = df['close'].pct_change()



    close       yield
0   9.836278    NaN
1   5.059823    -0.485596
2   0.842129    -0.833566
3   5.670353    5.733358
4   5.906502    0.041646
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the very good answer from **Z Li**, if you can't use **pct_change()**, you may try:

Creating a column with the previous values to compare, ie the values shifted by one.

```
df['prev_year_close'] = df['close'].shift(1)
```

Define a function we'll use to get the yield:

```
def getCGY(row):
    difference = row["close"] - row["prev_year_close"]
    return difference/row["prev_year_close"]
```

Use pandas' **apply()** to perform the above function on each row:

```
df['capital_gains_yield'] = df.apply( lambda x: getCGY(x), axis=1)
```

Optionally delete the comparison column:

```
df = df.drop("prev_year_close",axis=1)
```

Will output:

```
      close  capital_gains_yield
0  139.6180                  NaN
1  131.3644            -0.059116
2  159.8925             0.217168
3  215.7010             0.349038
```

This will give you a bit of flexibility in case you need to change the way calculation is made, etc. by editing the **getCGY** function.